# How to Dynamically Switch WiFi Networks in MAUI

Tags: android, network-programming, wifi, maui

We are looking for direction on how to do the following in Maui, or whether it is actually possible.  The device is Android.

At the start of the application, we want to save the following:  the current WiFi SSID or ESSID, the security mode, the WiFi network password, the current IP address, subnet mask, and DNS settings.

Then we want to change all of these settings to access a different network.

Then, at the end of the application, we want to reset all of these settings to the values they had at the start of the application.

By application, I mean an application created using Maui.

Comment: Unfornately, maui can not do that. You need to modify it manually.